# Adding a Listview to Case Statement

Tags: android

I have been playing around with this code for days now if someone can help. I have 10 imagebutton in one layout i have all the button clicks in a case statement which takes care of them.What i need is to have a listview inside all the buttons when clicked.Now i have some good code from Ridcully
[Listview On Multiple Button Clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476782/listview-on-multiple-button-clicks). I just can seem to get it to work

FirstActivity

```
                package com.example.testtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layout_of_button);
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
ImageButton btn4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
ImageButton btn5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
ImageButton btn6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    // if one of the image buttons is pressed...
    case R.id.imageButton1:
    case R.id.imageButton2:
    case R.id.imageButton3:
    case R.id.imageButton4:
    case R.id.imageButton5:
    case R.id.imageButton6:   
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Listviewact.class);
        // pass ID of pressed button to listview-activity
        intent.putExtra("buttonId", v.getId());  
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    // here you could place handling of other clicks if necessary...        
    }
}

  private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

 private ListView getListView() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
   }
 }
```

Listviewact

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.ListView;

    public class Listviewact extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);
  }

   public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int buttonId = getIntent().getIntExtra("buttonId", 0);
    int buttonIdx = getButtonIdx(buttonId);

    // find and set image according to buttonId
    int imageId = IMAGE_IDS[buttonIdx];        // image to show for given button
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId);

    // find and set listview imtes according to buttonId
    String[] items = LISTVIEW_DATA[buttonIdx]; // listview items to show for given button
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

// a little helper to map ids to array indices 
// to be able to fetch the correct image and listview data later
private final static int[] BUTTON_IDS = new int[] {
    R.id.imageButton1, 
    R.id.imageButton2, 
    R.id.imageButton3, 
    R.id.imageButton4, 
    R.id.imageButton5, 
    R.id.imageButton6
};

// 6 images
private final static int[] IMAGE_IDS = new int[] {
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher
};

// 6 different sets of strings for the listviews
private final static String[][] LISTVIEW_DATA = new String[][] {
    {"First A", "First B", "First C"},
    {"Second A", "Second B", "Second C"},
    {"Third A", "Third B", "Third C"},
    {"Forth A", "Forth B", "Forth C"},
    {"Fifth A", "Fifth B", "Fifth C"},
    {"Sixth A", "Sixth B", "Sixth C"},
};

// map button id to array index
static private int getButtonIdx(int id) {
    for(int i = 0; i<BUTTON_IDS.length; i++) {
        if (BUTTON_IDS[i] == id) return i;
    }
    return 0;    // should not happen
}
  }
```

when i start it the button click works but no listview ??

Comment: can you please elaborate neknek

Comment: change my code hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `listView.setListAdapter(adapter);` as shown in the example code of my answer to your previous question. You're calling your own `setListAdapter` method which does nothing, so the `listView` has no adapter to get the data from.

Comment: when i add the above it gets a error under setListAdapter say add cast to listview and change to setadapter

Comment: for some reason now it works this is what i have and it works listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Just need to make the listview look better as it looks just standard

Comment: hope you can help Ridcully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598355/open-multiple-listview-item-click-to-one-class